# Java Browser Commands and Download

Tags: java, browser, download, cloud

So I'm working on an application in Java that has to use database information from a cloud based server. I figured instead of making the user download the database manually, it'd be nice if this app could automatically retrieve this database. The problem is I don't know how or if it's even possible to do this in Java. 
We are working on multiple implementations of this, so we are using different services for each (iFormBuilder, epicollect, etc). 
Each of these services have a "download" button on their web interface, but I don't believe there are any simple commands to retrieve them besides that. 
What would you suggest to solve this problem?

Update: *sigh* so there are api's for the ones the other guys (I'm on a team of 3) are working on. However, they require buying a higher license than we have ($5K for api access? No thanks). So mostly, we are looking for a cheaper solution

Comment: Can you elaborate on "download the database" bit?

Comment: The data is stored as a .csv or .xls. It is simple field name and value data. I'd like to download it to a local directory where I can then use it in the app.
Or, if possible, being able to access it directly online without the download phase would be nice, except I can see problems occurring when the database gets updated during processing.

Comment: Typically services let you retrieve such data through a webservice call. Are you sure there's no published API to do so?

Comment: I don't believe so, I've looked for such and api for these services, and I haven't been able to find any. Maybe I need to search a bit harder. I'm working in a 3 man team so I've only really had in depth looks at 2 of them.

Comment: If you know the URLs to the files you need, you can simply use HttpClient or URLConnection for file retrieval.

Comment: The most reliable way is to use Firefox with Firebug addon, or Chrome browser with Developer Tools -> Network section open. Then navigate to download a file, and check in the Firebug/Chrome Network log where did the GET request go to to get your .csv file. That's your URL.

Comment: That's incredibly helpful. Thanks!
How do I add rep/upvote here? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can certainly help with IFormBuilder. In the IForm interface, you can hold shift to display the URL of the XML feed. This will return all the data in the table along with the subforms as child elements. Each record comes as a  element, so the xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<_data12345_my_table_name>
<record>
  <ID>12345</ID>
  <PARENT_RECORD_ID>0</PARENT_RECORD_ID>
  <field>value</field>
  <field2>value2</field>
  ...etc...
</record>
```

There will be one  element for each one.

One thing though - beware the <b> at the end, this is for display purposes only and should be ignored when importing data.

And this isn't part of the enterprise API, as far as I know.